Connecting SWD on a same pin as an I/O pin
I'm working on a PCB with a specific number of pins. There are 12 pins on the PCB, used by another device to transfer data and communicate with the chip. I have +3V3, GND, RST, pins for I/O, and an extra unused pin that's not connected to the device - so it's left floating.
I need to be able to connect to the RP2040 chip through SWD to flash or debug it, but I only have this unused pin available. I thought of using the unused pin for  SWCLK (which already has an internal pull-up) and any other I/O pin for  SWD (which has a pull-up as well, but it shouldn't cause any interference?)
I believe that the microcontroller "doesn't care" about the value of SWD as long as SWCLK isn't triggered. Is this OK? Is there any issue with this setup?

I don't think there will be an issue, but better safe than sorry. I don't know your particular MCU but it is probably possible to shut down SWD access once the MCU is programmed, aka "copycat protection". If you do that, then you don't have to worry about using the GPIO pin and causing some hiccups that way.
